# Where can I find a JAVA library of visual effects and image manipulation?

Tags: android, android-canvas, image-manipulation, java, visual-effects

I'm looking for to create an android app, and need to find a library of visual effects.

- For instance: - starting with a blank canvas
  (1) user draws a geometrical shape and everything in the shape changes color, 
  (2) user splits the screen and the images on either side of where the user split the screen flip and change into 2 separate colors,
  (3) drawing a circle on the screen will place everything on the canvas into 10 equally sized circles spread around the screen evenly.

These are just examples of visual effects I'm looking for, I'm hoping to find a full library.

Found some good effects here - http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/java/applets/visual-effects/
But I need a larger database.

- Looking for both free and pay-for effects.

Thank you very much in advance for any information.

Answer (score 0):

Try jhlabs: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/

Do you wanted to find similar effects? Jhlabs is pretty good for image processing in java. You can find other Graphics effects (strokes, shapes, java2d etc..) on http://jhlabs.com